# Fetch initial page data with ReactJS + Redux + Cloud Endpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-cloud-endpoints, react-redux

I use ReactJS + Redux + Google Cloud Endpoints. Now, for the initial page load I have to fetch and display data via Cloud Enpoints. How would that be accomplished? Full code examples appreciated!

Comment: Please give some example what you want do, and where you feel having a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically mount your app with a blank slate, be it with overlays, or loading spinners, and then fetch data inside `componentDidMount()`. From [the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html).

> ## Load Initial Data via AJAX
>
> Fetch data in componentDidMount. When the response arrives, store the
>   data in state, triggering a render to update your UI.
>
> When fetching data asynchronously, use componentWillUnmount to cancel
>   any outstanding requests before the component is unmounted.
>
> This example fetches the desired Github user's latest gist:
>
> ```js
> var UserGist = React.createClass({
>   getInitialState: function() {
>     return {
>       username: '',
>       lastGistUrl: ''
>     };
>   },
>
>   componentDidMount: function() {
>     this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
>       var lastGist = result[0];
>       this.setState({
>         username: lastGist.owner.login,
>         lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url
>       });
>     }.bind(this));
>   },
>
>   componentWillUnmount: function() {
>     this.serverRequest.abort();
>   },
>
>   render: function() {
>     return (
>       <div>
>         {this.state.username}'s last gist is
>         <a href={this.state.lastGistUrl}>here</a>.
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
> });
>
> ReactDOM.render(
>   <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
>   mountNode
> );
> ```